# Make gif loader show on click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, loading

I have a HTML input button which submits a PHP form when it is clicked. The code for that is as follows:

```
<input class="rg_btn" name="submit" value="Register" type="submit" />
```

However, when the user clicks that button, I want it to show a loading image for 3 seconds (I have the gif file) in the middle of the page then I want the form to actually process.

How would I do this?

Like what http://www.mega.co.nz/#pro does when you click Buy Now

Comment: Can you give a little more information? What is being done in the meantime? Do you want it to literally just fade after three seconds?

Comment: An `onClick` event and a `setTimeout` call. Pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I added a link about what I mean in the question just

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the image to your html and let it be hidden using CSS:

```
 <img src="3sec.gif" id="gif" style="display: none;">
```

Then, using jQuery:

```
 $('.rg_btn').submit(function() {
     $('#gif').show(); 
     return true;
 });
```

Also don't forget to include jQuery between the header tags if you don't already have it:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, this is simplest solution that can be find

Comment: Still works 9 years later... thanks!

Comment: Is this also possible without jQuery, e.g. with pure Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="rg_btn" name="submit" value="Register" type="submit" onclick='btnClick' />


function btnClick() {

    var Gif = document.createElement('div');

    Gif.className = "?";

    Gif.innerHTML = "<img src='some_img' />";

    document.appendChild(Gif);


    setTimeout("btnClickfade()", 3000);

}

function btnClickfade() {

     document.removeChild(document.getElementByClassName("?"));

}
```

Comment: Although, you probably don't want to do this in this fashion, I'm guessing. You're probably going to want to perform btnClick() with a reference to an external request, and in the external request's callback, fade the gif.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below-

STep 1: Do not create a submit button, rather create a standard button
Step 2: WHen user clicks on taht button, call a function lets name it submitme

STep 3:

In Javascript:
    function submitme()
    {
    //COde for displaying image for required time
    //hide the image and submit the form
    }

Answer (score 0):

For this you would have to create a function that fires onclick of the button which cancels the default behaviour (to submit the form) using [event.preventDefault();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) after that you would set the basically append a div to the body, with a centered loading gif (through CSS)
That will display for 3 seconds, You can also have the DIV pre-inserted so you won't have to append it anymore.

There are a few things I do not understand tho, from your question I can read that you want to show a loading gif for 3 seconds, this is awfully long and only after that you actually want to start processing the form.

For this case I would strongly suggest using AJAX to handle your request transparently, e.g. no page reloads, no 3 second delay on a submission.

And if the user has JS disabled, you could use the PHP fallback where the form would instantly submit (users will not want to wait 3 seconds trust me)

This is probably the most userfriendly way, If you have questions on how to implement an AJAX request with plain JS, comment this question and I will edit it accordingly to what you need.

‐ Sid